# Only account loses admin privileges when restarting

Tags: permissions, login

I am pretty new to linux, but I am running into an issue and it seems to break everything. I have tried searching, but can't find a similar problem anywhere. I am running Ubuntu 20.4.

When I first install the desktop system I create an account and everything works fine. There is only one account and it is the main account on the computer. Once I turn off or restart the computer, the account loses administrator privileges which prevents me from doing many things including something as simple as selecting a wifi network. I can't unlock the account, I can't even turn the computer off again without typing in the password for the account. I have tried to find some way to fix it and tried several of the suggested password terminal commands, but I can't seem to fix it without reinstalling the entire system and setting everything up again.

Screenshots: https://i.stack.imgur.com/SJgiF.jpg

Comment: I don't understand your issue; but the change is likely because of something you did in the last session before you encountered the problem. I also don't know what issues you're trying to describe? (is it you're not using `sudo` when you need to? or issues with a desktop? as you've not said if it was a server or desktop install). FYI:  You can re-install Ubuntu without it overwriting your files, or config/setup if you're talking about a desktop install, OR have it start with a fresh/new system with nothing surviving (thus need to reconfigure everything), both options of what install you action

Comment: I have to start fresh with a new desktop install every time I restart the computer. The second time I log in I am inundated with popups asking for a password to create a color space, refresh the repository, scan for wifi networks, or manage networks. I can't unlock my user account on the settings page because that option is greyed out. I can't control anything in the gui that requires administrator privileges because it asks for the admin password, which no longer works. I am not doing antything in terminal. The prior session is the first session and all I do is install google chrome.

Comment: The dialog looks like it is from polkit / policykit. Normally, such authentication is not required for a polkit `localuser` based on their membership of the `sudo` group - is your user in the `sudo` group? Check with the `id` command

Comment: According to the id command, yes the user is part of the sudo group.